# Show message for few seconds only; ASP.Net VS 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working on an ASP.Net page. When a user completes a task, a user control pops up and shows the status of the task viz. completed/failed. I want this user control to be set `visible=false` after 3 seconds. During these 3 seconds if the user requests another task, it shouldn't be hampered.

I've researched on *meta* tags but I don't want to refresh my page. Also using `Thread.Sleep` will block my page for 3 seconds which is something I don't want at all. Maybe starting a new thread and assigning this functionality is the way to go but as you can tell, I'm a novice and seeking expert advice should be fruitful. By the way this is my first ever post so I've come here with tons of expectations.

I have done some digging in threads and use of Ajax timers but I don't seem to nail it. This is why I've come here and seek your help.

Thanks in anticipation.

P.S - For some reason, I don't wish to accomplish this using *JQuery/Javascript*. I wish to use server side solely.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript for this. You're trying to manipulate the visibility of a client side html div/element. What is wrong with `RegisterStartupScript` and toggle the css visibility? This is where ASP.net fools you into thinking you can do this server side.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use JavaScript for this. You're trying to manipulate the visibility of a client side html div/element. What is wrong with `RegisterStartupScript` and toggle the css visibility? This is where ASP.net fools you into thinking you can do this server side.

On reload/postback/button click:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page),
              "showResponse","$('#myDiv').delay(3000).hide();", true);
```

Utilise Javascript timeouts `setTimeout` or jQuery's `delay()`

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0):

I assume using JQuery show function would resolve this

$control.show( [duration ] , [ complete ] ) / control.show(duration[int])